# Return instance of class to main

Tags: c++, templates

My program reads from a configuration file and instantiates several classes with the contents of two specific sections for each time.

To initialize `Voice` class, I'd call:

```
initializeDomain ("voice", voice_config, voice_config_fields);
```

and `Voice` should be initialized as:

```
Voice voice ( config, config_fields );
```

To do so, I programmed the following function:

```
void initializeDomain (string dom, map<string, string> & config, map<string, string> & config_fields)
{
    if ( dom == "voice" ) {
        Voice voice ( config, config_fields );
        return voice;
    } else if ( dom == "account" ) {
        Account account (config, config_fields);
        return account;
    }
}
```

This is obviously not working, as the return type is variable, depending on the class that is instantiated. So, I tried to build a template that could address this need:

```
template <typename T>
T initializeDomain (string dom, map<string, string> & config, map<string, string> & config_fields)
{
    if ( dom == "voice" ) {
        T instantiated ( config, config_fields );
    } else if ( dom == "account" ) {
        T instantiated ( config, config_fields );
    }
    return instantiated;                                                          }
}
```

But it does not work either.  How can I instantiate different classes in the template?

Comment: Can you show us how you would use such a method?

Comment: The code you're presenting (for the template version) will return a copy of the instance you've created not the instance itself. You won't be able to return a reference to the `T` object created on the local stack of `initializeDomain()`. I guess factory pattern should do what you want, but hard to say without seeing how you want to use it.

Comment: c++ doesnt support reflections (that is what you try to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like classic application for [Factory Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Allocate instances dynamically and return by [smart] pointer:

```
class Base {};
class DerivedOne : public Base {};
class DerivedTwo : public Base {};

typedef std::unique_ptr<Base> BasePtr;

BasePtr createFoo( /* arguments */ ) {
    BasePtr ptr; // initialized to nullptr
    if ( ... ) ptr.reset( new DerivedOne );
    else if ( ... ) ptr.reset( new DerivedTwo );
    else ...

    return ptr;
}
```

#### Edit 0:

The usage for above setup is for *polymorphic* types, i.e. when you have a common interface to different implementations, so you would invoke *virtual* methods *via pointer*, like:

```
BasePtr base = createFoo( /* args */ );
base->callVirtualFunction( /* args */ );
```

What you are talking about is a bit strange. C++ is strongly-typed language, i.e. you can't store instances of unrelated types into same variable. The simple case you are describing looks like this:

```
std::string value = getInputSomewhere();

if ( value == "voice" ) {
    Voice v( /* ctor args */ );
    // do your voice stuff here
} else if ( value == "account" ) {
    Account a( /* ctor args */ );
    // do your account stuff here
} else {
    // ...
}
```

So I don't really see what you are trying to accomplish with that template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it seems I can only use the pointer as: `Base b = * createFoo (arguments);`.  I'd like to `Voice v = * createFoo ("voice", other arguments)` and `Account a = * createFoo ("account", other arguments)`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are very confused about the C++ language.

Comment: These are advanced features of the language that I don't know and need some explanation to learn.  Will try to search for it in the www.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I would suggest using a factory pattern to allow feeding in your various types and returns the desired instance.   I hope that helps.

Comment: A factory will only help if `Voice` and `Account` are of the same base type. There is nothing in the question that indicated they are.

Comment: Not necessarily true.  The classes must all implement an interface or derive from a base class.  _"There is nothing in the question that indicated they are"_---**the question doesn't indicate that they aren't either**.

Answer (score 1):

It may not fit the question exactly without some assumptions, but with what we have to go on, I would have to agree with the factory pattern.

Good luck and please let us know how you resolved the issue?